# If statement working only until 1st else if

Tags: php

I am trying to show a different navigation bar depending on a users authority. Only problem is that when i log on to the system it shows the first else if, regardless of the authority of the user. To ensure that the problem is in the loop i have tried switching the else ifs and the same happened. the code is in an external php file and i call the function in the top of each page. any suggestions ?

```
function checkAuth() {
  session_start();

  if(!isset($_SESSION['role'])) {
    require_once('menu.php');
  } else if ($_SESSION['role'] = "registered") {
    require_once('regnav.php');
  } else if ($_SESSION['role'] = "admin") {
    echo "FDGFGFD";
    require_once('adminnav.php');
  }

}
```

Comment: you must use a double `=` sign for any condition check.

Comment: i have tried using the double == , but when i do so no navbar appears

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is with this part: `$_SESSION['role'] = "registered"`.  The single `=` means you are assigning the value "registered" to variable `$_SESSION['role']`.

If you are evaluating to check something, you need to use `==` i.e. `$_SESSION['role'] == "registered"`

You'll have the same issue with the second `elseif`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a double `=` sign for any condition check. For any condition check in `if` or `else if`, you have to use `==` in the middle of the variables.

If you use only `=` that means it assigning the value in the `$_SESSION['role']`. Also you can use `===` for checking the value as well as the type of the variable.

Valid function is:

```
function checkAuth()
{
session_start();


if(!isset($_SESSION['role']))
{
    require_once('menu.php');
}

else if ($_SESSION['role'] == "registered"){
    require_once('regnav.php');
}

else if ($_SESSION['role'] == "admin"){
    echo "FDGFGFD";
    require_once('adminnav.php');
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Or use `===` to check for types too. That prevents unexpected results if `$_SESSION['role']` is 0.

Comment: that is also true...